# Express polynomial as product of irreducible factors over fields

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

I've seen some similar questions around but I'll post this up anyways. There's this beautiful polynomial: $$z^4-z^3-5z^2-z-6$$ and I am to factorise it into a irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$. But it looks super gross and I don't know where to start. I tried to factorise it with $z^2$ at the front but it it turned out to be a bunch of fractions and roots which I found suspicious.

I have this strong feeling that I might've forgotten some crucial theory/formulae to make my life much easier.

Comment: Is $z$ correct?

Comment: @Moo I just realised that I miswrote the equation! EDIT: fixed!

Comment: $$z^4-z^3-5z^2-z-6 = (z-3) (z+2) \left(z^2+1\right)$$

Comment: @Moo Thank you; but how did you reach to that conclusion? Was there a concept, etc that sets it up?

Comment: Look at the factors of leading and ending terms $6 \implies 1,6, 2, 3$ and see if one works.

Comment: Rational root theorem. For a monic polynomial, always test ($\pm$) the divisors of $6$ as potential roots of the expression. Once this was done in this case, we landed with an unfactorable quadratic. Over $\mathbb C$, though, we can complete the factorization to get $(z-i)(z+i)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
 z^4-z^3-5z^2-z-6  &=&  (z^4-5z^2-6)-(z^3+z)\\
   &=& (z^2-6)(z^2+1)-z(z^2+1) \\
   &=& (z^2+1)(z^2-6-z)\\
    &=&  (z^2+1)(z-3)(z+2)
\end{eqnarray*}

In $\mathbb{C}$

$$ ...=(z+i)(z-i)(z-3)(z+2)$$